# How much IV do I need from a WPA2 wifi to capture EAPOL with aircrack-ng

Tags: encryption, wifi, aircrack-ng

I am trying to "crack" my own wifi for study. I have a very cheap router, it uses WPA2.

I use the latest aircrack-ng tool for this.

My question is about the amount of IV I need for the EAPOL to be captured. 
I read through the manuals, and all I could find is that the #Data shown while capturing information on a channel is not the exact amount if IV, and that for a WEP encrypted wifi I need around 40-85k IV to capture the handshake.

Can anyone elaborate on the #Data number? How do this relate to the IVs? Approximately how much IV do I need to capture the handshake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to grab the WPA handshake (EAPOL packets).

WEP has a security flaw that allows a statistical analysis attack on the IVs (collected through data) to recover the passphrase.

To recover a WPA passphrase with aircrack-ng it is harder: you need the WPA handshake, and then you have to crack it with a dictionary attack or brute-force attack.

The handshake between the router and the client is done in the authentication phase of the connection, so you either have to force re-authentication (with `aireplay-ng -0`, deauthentication attack) or you have to wait for a client to establish a new connection with the router.

Comment: Yeah i figured out by trial and error buy now, thanks for the replay!